# How can I change the text of a button when it is disabled using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I have a SAVE button that is disabled when a form is pristine.   I want it to say SAVED when pristine and then change to SAVE when the form is dirty.  Working fine except the text change for the button.  Here is the code:

```
     <input type="button" value="SAVED" class="button success radius expand" ng-click="save(form)" ng-disabled="!signupform.$dirty" ng-class="{disabled:!signupform.$dirty}">
```

Comment: What do you mean by pristine vs dirty?

Comment: The form is either pristine or dirty.

Comment: Why -1? $pristine and $dirty are valid angularjs properties.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController#$pristine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make inline just do:

```
<input type="button" value="{{(signupform.$dirty)? 'save' : 'saved'}}" class="button success radius expand" ng-click="save(form)" ng-disabled="!signupform.$dirty" ng-class="{disabled:!signupform.$dirty}">
```

You can also create a function in your controller to return the text. This can be useful if your logic is larger (different texts for various specific cases).

**html**

```
     <input type="button" value="{{getInputText()}}" class="button success radius expand" ng-click="save(form)" ng-disabled="!signupform.$dirty" ng-class="{disabled:!signupform.$dirty}">
```

**controller**:

```
function getInputText(form) {
    return (form.$dirty)? 'save' : 'saved';
}
```